# What does a space of functions sorted by how they grow asymptotically look like?

Tags: computational-complexity

Let's define two computable functions as equal iff they are calculated in the same time in Big-O terms.

Is this an equivalence relation? If yes, how many equivalence classes are there? What does that structure look like?

Is this an ordering, one function growing faster than another? If so, what does the structure of that ordering look like?